# Конечное число попыток входа

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Всем *Привет*!

Собственно вопрос, как реализовать механизм входа пользователя на сайт. Если используется `Custom Membership`, и нужно чтобы максимальное число попыток входа ровнялось допустим 3, без возможности обойти этот механизм. Как узнать что это именно Та тачка, тот пользователь который занимается подбором Логин+Пароль.

Реализовывается это на уровне Сессий или на уровне определения IP(в этом я вообще уверен нет смысла). Подскажите как реализовать данную задачу!

По всей видимости придётся привязываться к Логину пользователя. И делать механизм отслеживания неудачных попыток входа за определённый промежуток времени конкретного пользователя.

А ещё есть какие нибудь варианты?

Comment: Не ужели ни у кого нет идей и опыта работы с такими задачами?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы и комментарии к этому вопросу: [Как защититься от чрезмерной "пробивки" адресов через обработчик ajax запросов?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/129678/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%87%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Да блочить вредные Dinamic IP круто это решает проблему с DDoS но, как бы у меня проблема ни с этим, а с идентификацией пользователя, мне нужно определить сколько раз подряд Некто засунул в скважину  не тот ключ. И да блочка по Dinamic IP возможно мне бы подошла, но как это всё завязать вместе?